# Limiting Distribution of $W_n=\frac{Z_n}{n^2}$ , $Z_n \sim \chi ^2 (n)$

Tags: probability, self-study, convergence, asymptotics, moment-generating-function

My try ended in an awkward result. I thought it best to use the moment generating function (MGF) technique. We can derive the MGF of $W_n$ as follows:

$$ E \left[ e^{tZ /n^2} \right]= \left(1-\frac{2t}{n^2} \right)^{-n/2}$$ from the chi-squared MGF. But the problem is that the limit of that as $n \to \infty$ leaves $1$ and I am left puzzled whether I did everything right. Have I missed something? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your calculation is correct. You simply need to interpret it. Which distribution has an MGF identically equal to 1?

Alternatively, your problem can be approached without using MGFs. Recall that $\chi^2(n)$ has the distribution of a sum of $n$ squares of $N(0,1)$ random variables. What can you say about the limiting distribution of
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n X_k^2,$$
if $X_k\sim N(0,1)$?

Comment: Why are you dividing by $n$ in the above? The sum of iid chi-squared RVs is chi-squared with degrees of freedom equal to the respective sum. It could be a degenerate distribution at 0.

Comment: @JohnK You should think about the question phils is asking you to consider. There's a good reason to think about what a $\chi^2_n/n$ is in the limit; if you can see what it is, the answer to the original question becomes obvious, and the meaning of the MGF result you got (if it wasn't already clear) is readily seen.

Comment: @Glen_b It is $n^2$ .I think it's a degenerate distribution at 0, like I said above. I know that the mgf of a degenerate distribution at some $k$ is $e^{kt}$. Now put $k=0$ and it is equal to 1.

Comment: Yes it's correct, but I can't tell whether you think it because you already have the MGF or whether you actually thought about what the limiting distribution of a chi-square on its degrees of freedom is (which as soon as I read your question was how I knew what it would be without doing any calculation).

Comment: @JohnK Your answer is correct. The idea behind my suggestion is that the law of large numbers tells us that if we divide by just $n$, we obtain in the limit the expectation of $X_1^2$, which is 1. Thus dividing by anything that grows faster, such as $n^2$, we obtain $0$ almost surely, hence the limit is degenerate at $0$.

Comment: @Glen_b I am a beginner on asymptotics so what you are suggesting did not cross my mind, I admit. Hopefully with practice I will get there. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer here gives a useful hint as to what happens.  I'm going to show you another aspect of the problem.  Using the moment generating functions, it is simple to show that:

$$n W_n = \frac{Z_n}{n} \sim \text{Ga} \bigg( \text{Shape} = \frac{n}{2}, \ \text{Rate} = \frac{n}{2} \bigg).$$

This random variable has mean and variance:

$$\mathbb{E}(n W_n) = 1
\quad \quad \quad \mathbb{V}(n W_n) = \frac{2}{n},$$

and so asymptotically, we have $n W_n \rightarrow 1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.  Given that this is true, what do you think happens asymptotically to $W_n$?

Answer (score 0):

The limit should be degenerate at 0.

pf: Zn/n2=(Zn/n)(1/n) ;
Zn/n → 1 in probability, 1/n → 0 in probability ;

Thus (Zn/n)(1/n) → 0 in probability and that equals (Zn/n)(1/n) → 0 in distribution such that Zn/n2 is degenerate at 0